# Build Pipeline Plugin - Jenkins - Showing only LAST Build Number of child job and only once (called from Post build action)

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-2, build-pipeline-plugin

[Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/): 2.89.4.x (or rolling)

[Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) version: 1.5.8

High level info:

I have JobA (parent), which calls JobB (twice in Build Step - either sequential or parallel) and calls the same JobB (twice in Post-Build Action). JobB is simple. It has just one parameter 'what' and each time Job A calls JobB, I'm passing a different parameter 'what' value.

```
A ->B -> (->B,->B in parallel)
  ->B
```

- Therefore, there are 4 times call to JobB per one pipeline run of JobA.
  i.e.

**NOTE:** This value of 'what' parameter printed in JobB's console output and using *Set Build Description*(plugin) for all 4 calls - WORKS!

**ISSUES 2 of them:**

1. Build Pipeline View is showing the LAST BUILD# of JobB in the GUI/Visual page.
2. Build-Step calls JobB twice and it's showing up in Build Pipeline View two times (as expected) **but** Post-Build Step which calls **JobB twice**, is **NOT** showing in the GUI page.

### **Job Config / Run Info:**

**JobA's configuration is:**
[image]

**JobB's configuration is:**
[image]

**JobA's console output is:**
[image]

**Pipeline view showing JobA and JobB (GUI) is:**
[image]

**JobB's job history is:**
[image]

Comment: I used ${BUILD_STATUS} in the `Customize Task Description Template` for the `Delivery Pipeline configuration` of the child jobs. If the second build succeeds and the first doesn't, then it shows up as `Fixed` instead of `Successful`. This only works with projects with a child with two builds.